# Java - Regular expression to match specific text

Tags: java, regex

I have multiple values in a Rate Column

Value is as below:

```
20
10
invalidtext
<blank>
NA
n/a
#NA
```

I have tried using the below pattern

```
"^0-9"   // If input value is not a numeric value (0-9) then replace it with null
```

But this will replace all text values if any in the column with null, 
And I want to replace only values which are having values as na, n/a, #na (Values can be Caps or small) with null using regular expression and keep value "invalidtext" as it is.

Any help on how to set such a specific single pattern check? Because I don't want to use multiple replace statements.

Comment: That pattern needs to be inside `[]` as `[^0-9]`. Right now, your pattern is matching `^` (start of the line), then `0`, then `-`, then `9`.

Comment: why don't you just use something like this? if you already know what you need to replace: `(na|NA|#na|#NA|n/a|N/A)`

Comment: You can use `str = str.replaceFirst("\\d*\\D.*", "null");`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text is a multiline text, you may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?mi)^(?!invalidtext$)[^\\d\r\n]*n/?a[^\\d\r\n]*$", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X0A0nR/1/)

**Details**

- `(?mi)` - MULTILINE and IGNORECASE flags are on
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!invalidtext$)` - the line cannot be equal to `invalidtext`
- `[^\d\r\n]*` - 0+ chars  other than digits, CR and LFs
- `n/?a` - `n/a` or `na`
- `[^\d\r\n]*` - 0+ chars  other than digits, CR and LFs
- `$` - end of a line.